# Is there a way to define type with template that takes optional specific enum and infinite types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have enum with some values and struct that converts it to a type.

```
enum class Types : uint8_t {
    ...
}; 

template<Types type>
struct enum_ {
    ...
}
```

I also have main template class Action, which is a lambda-like struct with overloaded operator(), depending on passed types

```
template<typename...>
struct Action;

template<typename T>
struct Action<T> { ... };

template<typename T, typename R>
struct Action<T, R> { ... };
```

The problem is that some of template parameters can be enums (e.g `T = enum_<Types::type>`)

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
template<typename... Args>
using ActionType = Action<Args...>;

template<Types type, typename... Args>
using ActionType = Action<enum_<type>, Args...>;
```

so in this case `T` is an optional enum type. I now I can use like this `ActionType<enum_<Types::type>, ...>`, but I am interested if this problem has a workaround.

Comment: "The problem is that some of template parameters can be enums" - it is not clear how this is a problem. Are you basically asking how to use type template parameter and a non-type template parameter on the same spot?

Comment: "I am interested if this problem has a workaround." - it seems to me that you're using a good enough workaround; maybe you can think the translate it in `Action` specializations.

Comment: @VTT, some sort of. I guess there's no way to put non-type template parameter to `typename...`, so I tried to think about different solution, but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: [std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) might replace `enum_`.

Comment: Parameter packs can contain both type and non-type template parameters, so it's still not clear why one of the params being an enum is a problem. Do you mean you want to wrap any non-type enum param in the `enum_` wrapper? Or you want to specialize `Action` for these types? Or something else?

Comment: @Useless, if I have `template<typename...> struct Action {};` and `enum class Types {};` I can't write something like `Action<Types::type, int> a; Action<int> b;`

Comment: @Useless I'd say that they can contain either only type or only non-type parameters, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Could you give the two flavors of `ActionType` different names? Something like `TypedAction` vs `UntypedAction`?

Comment: I am having hard time understanding this. I also agree with max66. Please explain more. Is how to have a mixed type, non-type(and non-template) parameter pack for a template your question? if not I also agree with Useless.